# Custom transformation in FME

Tags: fme-form

I'm trying to use a custom coordinate transformation in FME 2016.

I have defined the following transformation  in the file "MyCoordsSysDefs.fme":

```
XFORM_DEF Test \
SRC_DTM ED50 \
TRG_DTM ETRS89 \
DESC_NM "7 parametros" \
GROUP "Custom" \
INVERSE Yes \
MAX_ITR 8 \
CNVRG_VAL 1e-09 \
ERROR_VAL 1e-06 \
METHOD 7PARAMETER \
DELTA_X -130.5090 \
DELTA_Y -89.9490 \
DELTA_Z -145.9030 \
BWSCALE 5.2690 \
ROT_X 3.1126 \
ROT_Y -0.4718 \
ROT_Z 3.3181
```

I can't find how to use this in the offical documentation . How can I tell FME to use this transformation instead of the default one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly I would put the contents of this into a text file with a .fme extension and place it into \FME\CoordinateSystems - I think that's better than using MyCoordSysDefs.fme (because a. other people can share it and b. it's less likely to get overwritten if you install a new FME version).

To use it, choose Tools > FME Options > Coordinate Systems. Pick the reprojection you are carrying out and choose Edit. In there is a drop-down menu in which to select the transformation.

You can't remove the grid file that gets preference, but you can make sure that grid file doesn't exist on your system, forcing FME to use the backup transformation.

See a quick video demo I made at: https://www.screencast.com/t/uD8Y0T5pwB